# How to invert $f(x)=\dfrac{2^x}{1+2^x}$

Tags: functions, exponential-function, inverse

I know that if
$$f(x)=\frac{2^x}{1+2^x}$$

then

$$f^{-1}(x)=\log_2 \frac{x}{1-x} $$

How can I show this?

Comment: Try dividing the numerator & denominator by $2^x$ and then see if you can finish.

Comment: What does convert mean in this context?

Comment: find its inverse... I have the answer I just don't know how to get there

Comment: So what you're asking is to show that if $f(x)=2^x/(1+2^x)$, then $f^{-1}(x)=\log_2(x/(1-x))$, right?

Comment: yes. How do I get there?

Comment: Hint. Let $f(x) = x/(1+x)$ and $g(x) = 2^x$.  Then let $h(x) = f(g(x)) = 2^x/(1+2^x)$.  Now use $h^{-1}(x) = g^{-1}(f^{-1}(x)$ (note the order has switched.)  So if you happen to remember the inverse of $f(x) = x/(1+x)$ then you can do this problem in your head with no algebra to work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x = \frac{2^{y}}{1 + 2^{y}} \iff x(1 + 2^{y}) = 2^{y} \iff x + x2^{y} = 2^{y} \iff x = 2^{y} - x2^{y} = 2^{y} (1- x) \iff \frac{x}{1-x} = 2^{y} \iff y = \log_{2}(\frac{x}{1-x})$

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!